Does Ubuntu update TPM chip in Dell desktops?
Does Ubuntu update the TPM chip to the latest version? I'm just curious because I had to use the SSD with Windows, but I no longer use Windows.

Ubuntu applies firmware updates from manufacturers, but how this is done varies on Ubuntu product/release and you've not given any specifics. On my own release it's handled by firmware-updater which is a snap package; meaning users who've disabled snapd or snaps won't find their systems upgrading anything related to firmware.

Do you mean TMP or TPM?

Are you asking that if your Dell desktop came with TPM 1.0 chip, can Ubuntu replace that chip with a TPM 2.0? The answer is no. Ubuntu does not know how to use a screwdriver to open the desktop case. Neither can Ubuntu use a soldering iron.
